# want to minus datetime indatabase from current Datetime in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

i want to minus datetime in database table from current datetime and want to compare with greater than(>) operator

i want to compare current datetime and datetime in the database what i want is if my date from database minus current date is greater than 30 days then i want to show my label red else default

here it is what i have tried

```
       <label style="@(DateTime.Now-item.NewLinen>30 ? "color:red;": "")">New Linen</label>
```

I am getting red line below this and showing messege

> operator cannot be applied to operands of type 'timespan?' and int>

please help me with this

Comment: That's because it doesn't know what you want to compare - `>30` 30 seconds? 30 hours? 30 millennia (actually, I don't think `TimeSpan` supports that last one)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever so what is solution to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would usually shift the framing about slightly, and use something like this:

```
<label style="@((item.NewLinen.HasValue && item.NewLinen.Value.AddDays(30) < DateTime.Now) ? "color:red;": "")">New Linen</label>
```

But it's more a matter of taste. If you want to use `TimeSpan`, you need to construct another one to compare against and make it, *specifically*, 30 days long, not 30 seconds or any other units (which is why direct comparison with `int` isn't allowed)

Comment: So is `NewLinen` a *nullable* `DateTime`? If so, what do you want to happen when it is in fact `null` (and then I can correct my answer taking these details into account).